# How to fill up missing rows in a PySpark Dataframe with a combination of existing values and an input list of possible values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following PySpark Dataframe:

```
Product    Location    Date        Stock
Apple      L1          2023-01-01  100
Apple      L2          2023-01-15  30
Banana     L1          2023-01-01  10
Banana     L1          2023-01-08  20
Orange     L2          2023-01-01  50
```

Next to this I have a list with all possibilities for the Date Column:

```
dates = [2023-01-01, 2023-01-08, 2023-01-15]
```

Now I want the Dataframe to contain a row for each existing combination of `Product` and `Location` and all dates from the `dates` list, where the `Stock` value for each newly added row should be equal to 0.

The output DataFrame would look like this:

```
Product    Location    Date        Stock
Apple      L1          2023-01-01  100
Apple      L1          2023-01-08  0
Apple      L1          2023-01-15  0
Apple      L2          2023-01-15  30
Apple      L2          2023-01-01  0
Apple      L2          2023-01-08  0
Banana     L1          2023-01-01  10
Banana     L1          2023-01-08  20
Banana     L1          2023-01-15  0
Orange     L2          2023-01-01  50
Orange     L2          2023-01-08  0
Orange     L2          2023-01-15  0
```

Notes:

- Some combinations of `Product` and `Location` are not already in the list and thus should not be added (i.e. `(Banana, L2)` or `(Orange, L1)`)
- The possible values in `dates` are all sundays, but that does not add any extra complexity to the algorithm since the `dates` values are given in a fixed list

I think Window functions in PySpark could be useful here, but I could not find any example in which missing rows are filled up by a given list of values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to achieve it would be to create a dataframe with all possible date rows and then `join` the `stock` field.

here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    select('product', 'location'). \
    dropDuplicates(). \
    withColumn('dates', func.array(*[func.lit(k) for k in dates])). \
    selectExpr('product', 'location', 'explode(dates) as date'). \
    join(data_sdf, ['product', 'location', 'date'], 'left'). \
    fillna(0, subset=['stock']). \
    orderBy('product', 'location', 'date'). \
    show()

# +-------+--------+----------+-----+
# |product|location|      date|stock|
# +-------+--------+----------+-----+
# | Apple |      L1|2023-01-01|  100|
# | Apple |      L1|2023-01-08|    0|
# | Apple |      L1|2023-01-15|    0|
# | Apple |      L2|2023-01-01|    0|
# | Apple |      L2|2023-01-08|    0|
# | Apple |      L2|2023-01-15|   30|
# | Banana|      L1|2023-01-01|   10|
# | Banana|      L1|2023-01-08|   20|
# | Banana|      L1|2023-01-15|    0|
# | Orange|      L2|2023-01-01|   50|
# | Orange|      L2|2023-01-08|    0|
# | Orange|      L2|2023-01-15|    0|
# +-------+--------+----------+-----+
```